# How to stop Log4Net from creating an empty log file

Tags: log4net, log4net-configuration

I have stopped all appenders from writing logs to a file by adding `<log4net threshold="OFF" />`. Now I want to stop Log4net from creating the empty log file. Any idea how? Thanks in advance!

RootAppender:

```
<appender name="RootRollingFileAppender" type="log4net.Appender.RollingFileAppender">
  <file value="D:\Documents\DEBUG.log" />
  <appendToFile value="true" />
  <rollingStyle value="Size" />

  <maxSizeRollBackups value="2" />

  <maximumFileSize value="10000KB" /> ...
</appender>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to stop log4net from creating the empty log file by removing the `<file >` child element of the appender, along with the related properties, and setting `<appendToFile value="false" />`. The modified configuration is as follows:

```
<log4net threshold="OFF">
```

...

```
  <appendToFile value="false" />
  <rollingStyle value="Size" />
  <rollingStyle value="Composite" />

</appender>
<!-- END ROOT APPENDER -->
</log4net>
```